# How to calculate Elo overall rating?

Tags: algorithm, math, calculator, rating-system

I am working on a site that shows a ladder something like below. I am able to get the information like the top two rows but not the last `Overall` rating (Elo of 1927). I have tried the mean method but it produces lower results and they seem inaccurate.

So how can this be done, does anyone know of any formula that I can use to achieve this?

The data below is from [Voobly](http://www.voobly.com/profile/view/123288046/Ratings).

```
Ladder Statistics
Game ______________ Ladder __________ Rating ____ Wins __ Losses ___ Streak
AoE III: Vanilla __ 1v1 Supremacy ___ 1811 ______ 52 ____ 20 _______ 4
AoE III: Vanilla __ TGSupremacy _____ 1716 ______ 17 ____ 3 ________ 2
AoE III: Vanilla __ Overall _________ 1927 ______ 69 ____ 23 _______ 0
```

Comment: I don't understand, please clarify your question. What is exactly given and what should be calculated? You are given first two rows and want to predict rating for 3rd row knowing only wins and losses?

Comment: The overall ELO rating for a player is defined by all the matches they played (and the ELO of the opponent). To compute the ELO of a player you really need to process every match by all players since your data collection started. As you move from oldest to newest matches you keep an ongoing ELO rating for each player (and they are updated as you process each match). I know from experience since I handle Backgammon ELO systems. That would give the *most* precision.

Comment: No, it also takes into account the all the games ever played. Here is my website and a profile of a player that has played both 1vs1's and team games. http://exciple.com/forum/player.php?n=_apocalyps All the data required to calculate is on that one page. I have figured out how to get the overall of the streak section, but only the overall rating is bugging me.

Comment: That is what I said. It takes into account all the games ever played. Unfortunately voobly requires registration to look at the data

Comment: Ok I will have a look into it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not be the way ELO works exactly, one valid way of doing rating systems is to award max(1, (other's rating - your rating)/25 + 16) to you when you beat other, and to dock that amount of points from other after they lost to you.  New users would start with a rating of 1200.  (This is how ratings in chess work.)